# Laravel 5.2 is not update parent's timestamp after updating child

Tags: laravel, eloquent, touches

In Laravel framework, I have 2 models. First is question model:

```
class Question extends Model
{
     protected $table = 'questions';
     protected $fillable = [...];
     public function answers()
     {
         return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Answer');
     }
     ...
}
```

And Answer model:

```
class Answer extends Model
{
     protected $table = 'answers';
     protected $fillable = [...];
     protected $touches = ['question'];
     public function question()
     {
         return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Question');
     }
     ...
}
```

I updated some attribute in answer model with code:

```
$answer = $answer->select('id')
            ->where('id', $id)
            ->firstOrFail();
$answer->update($data);
```

When I check database, data in Answers table is updated including updated_at column. However, its parent (Questions table) does not update timestamp in updated_at column.

How to solve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: Just some quick sanity checks: does your `answers` table have a `question_id` field (to verify relationship is setup correctly)? does your `answers` table have a `question` field (to verify field name isn't conflicting with relationship attribute)?

Comment: My answers table have question_id as foreign key and does not have question field.

Comment: Does the `answers` table have a `touches` field? Does it work if you manually call `$answer->question()->touch()`?

Comment: No, answers table does not have a touches field. The call $answer->question()->touch() does not work. However, if I call $question = Question::find($questionId); $question->touch(); , it works.

Comment: It sounds like the relationship is not working. What does `dd($answer->question)` show? Is `id` the primary key for the `questions` table?

Comment: why is this question downvoted? Seems to me a perfectly reasonable question...

Answer (score 0):

Just go with basics do something like following:

```
Question::find($questionId)->touch();
```

This will update timestatmp that you want to do.

Comment: This way is more complex if I have many functions which requires updating or if I have many nested relationships.